# Typescript type narrow on function arguments

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Here we have a union type which discriminated an object with different properties. A type guard has also be created to help narrow down the type. The type guard does not seems to work when the object is treated as function argument.

I first come up with this issue with React component props, then found out that this cound be replicate with typescript.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAkmASgQzAcwKYwLwwAUAbmgDYCu2AXDAORp0wA+9ARk63cJ-QCZ0AlLVKVcCejxb8meAHwwA3gCgYamACdsUChrAxRVfHgLdOrQ7hOmBygL7Ll2AB4AHEBthQAnq9wBlEABbbAAxCjBgAAUNEFcIfFV1VhV1NPgobCDaBl46DiT0mFAgoPBaaA04LEL0zOgAJlo2EBAybAxahzSU2rS4TOzJPNsitRKysAqoKpqxmHqoAEZaMAogtmwNLsdQSFgIYLCI4HwiV1j42kCQ8MiYuIhBfAVU9TgAMyIEZHQsbEIF0eADoBllBM83kUAPTQmBbWIaACEKL66j2h3awLIIEwgMuEGBiyWgh29mUQA)

```js
const isInRange = (value: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'): value is 'c' | 'd' => {
    return value === 'c' || value === 'd'
}

export type SomeFuncProps =
    | {
        item: 'a' | 'b'
        common: string
        test2: boolean
    }
    | {
        item: 'c' | 'd'
        common: string
        test1: number
    }

const someFunc = (props: SomeFuncProps) => {
    if (isInRange(props.item)) {
        // error!!!
        console.log(props.test1)
    }

}
```

Tried to put the type guard outside of a function, it can sucessfully narrow down the object passed to it, but cannot narrow when a function argument is passed to it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being inside or outside a function; when you write `const props: SomeFuncProps = {  item: "c", common: '123',  test1: 123 }` the type of `props` is automatically narrowed by the assignment, so it's already narrowed before you call your custom type predicate function (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOrkRW)).  Could you [edit] to remove the red herring about being in a function and just leave the actual issue intact?

Comment: (see prev comment) also, maybe you can just use `"a" | "b"` and `"c" | "d"` directly instead of using lots of `Exclude` verbiage?  It makes it hard to understand what types are where `Exclude<All, ExcludeRangeType>` vs `ExcludeRangeType` is quite confusing. ... and also it seems your test is *backwards*, where `isInExcludeRange(props.item)` should imply that it has `test2` but you are checking for `test1`.  Could you please [edit] to fix all these so we can proceed?  Thanks.

Comment: (see prev 2 comments).  Once you [edit] to fix those, the issue here is a limitation of TS described at [ms/TS#49782](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49782); type predicates cannot act directly on discriminant properties to narrow the parent object.  For now the workaround is pass the parent object in, either programmatically or hardcoded, both are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKrGpm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'llw rite up a full answer (after we [edit] to fix the question); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thanks @jcalz! I think the gh issue you mentioned had answered my question. I really appreciate the solution you have provided. 

Comment: Okay, great.  Do you mind making the edits to your question that I suggested, and then I'll write up an answer?  Or if you don't want to make the edits, do you mind if I do?